# Python Extract href Problems

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm trying to get all a href from a url. The problem is I can't extract the write a href:

`<a href="#!DetalleNorma/203906/20190322" title="" data-bind="html: organismo, attr: {href: $root.crearHrefDetalleNorma(idTamite,fechaPublicacion)} ">SECRETARÍA GENERAL</a>`

All I can extract is: #!

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request as urllib2
import re

html_page = urllib2.urlopen('https://www.boletinoficial.gob.ar/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
for link in soup.findAll('a'):
    print link.get('href')
```

Here is with the parse. It is not working too:

```
import requests
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.boletinoficial.gob.ar/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

for td in soup.findAll("div", class_="itemsection"):
    for a in td.findAll("a", href=True):
        print(a.text)
```

Comment: 1. Use a html parser

Comment: @DirtyBit they are...

Comment: @JonClements Would throw `UserWarning: No parser was explicitly specified, ` in Python 3.x

Comment: @DirtyBit depends on the version...

Comment: There are multiple hrefs for each DECRETO ... do you need only the first or all of them?

Comment: @JonClements Don't kill for editing my comment! :D

Comment: @DirtyBit haha... no - I meant which version of BeautifulSoup4 is in use...

Comment: I need all DECRETO hrefs @QHarr

Comment: Do you want the `urls` or the `text`?

Comment: Both. @DirtyBit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to use selenium with a wait condition

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.boletinoficial.gob.ar/')
links =  [item.get_attribute('href') for item in WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".itemsection [href]")))]
print(links)
```

Text and link as tuples

```
data =  [(item.get_attribute('href'), item.text) for item in WebDriverWait(driver,20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".itemsection [href]")))]
print(data)
```

Comment: I knew we would have to end up doing something like this! +1

Comment: @DirtyBit Yeah... I tried with requests but [computer said no](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJQ3TM-p2QI)